# In Playwright, how to pass a baseUrl via command line so my spec files dont have a hardcoded url for the app I am testing?

Tags: playwright

In Protractor, I am currently passing a flag in the command line that indicates what my URL is for the app I am testing. And now we are switching to Playwright, I want to do something similar. Since the same tests will be used to test the app in different environments (dev, test, CI) I need a way to pass different URLs and ideally it will be nice if I can control that via command line.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The `baseURL` option has been added in Playwright v1.13.0.

```js
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  use: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000',
  },
};
export default config;
```

Currently, in Playwright Test v1.12.0 there is no `baseUrl` property as we have in Protractor. But you can accomplish it with a system variable.

For instance:

```js
import { test } from '@playwright/test';

const BASE_URL = process.env.URL;

test('verify title of the page', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto(BASE_URL);
});
```

and then run it on dev env:

```sh
URL=https://playwright.dev npx playwright test
```

or prod:

```sh
URL=https://playwright.prod npx playwright test
```

Answer (score 2):

I added an environment variable to the `playwright.config.js` and it seems to work here.

```js
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config = {
  use: {
      baseUrl: process.env.MY_CUSTOM_BASE_URL
    }
  }
```

then run something like the answer above.

`MY_CUSTOM_BASE_URL=https://example.com npx playwright test`

or

```
export MY_CUSTOM_BASE_URL=https://example.com
npx playwright test
```

Answer (score 0):

playwright version 1.41.1.

For example, for testing in your dev environment, you can create an extra config file `playwright.dev.config.ts` and put the base url and other variables based on your local configs.

```
import config from "./playwright.config";

const devConfig = {
    ...config,
    webServer: {
        port: 3000,
        timeout: 120 * 1000,
        reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
    },
};

if (devConfig.use) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line fp/no-mutation
    devConfig.use.baseURL = "http://localhost:3000/";
}

export default devConfig;
```

The command line for it would be:

```
npx playwright test --config=playwright.dev.config.ts
```

Those URL variable in command line did not work for me. Now I have three config files for three stages(local, dev and production).