# Playwright - Test against different environments and different variables

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

Im looking to use Playwright to test against a web page.

The system im working on has 4 different environments that we need to deploy against,
for example the test urls may be

`www.test1.com`
`www.test2.com`
`www.test3.com`
`www.test4.com`

The first question is how do I target the different Environment? In my playwright config I had a baseUrl but I need to override that.

In addition each environment has different login credentials, how can I create and override these as parameters per environment?

Comment: This could be helpfule: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68210919/in-playwright-how-to-pass-a-baseurl-via-command-line-so-my-spec-files-dont-have

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Playwright `v1.13.0`, there is a `baseURL` option available. You can utilise that in this way probably

In your `config.js` file, you can have this

```
import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from '@playwright/test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  use: {
    baseURL: process.env.URL,
  },
};
export default config;
```

Now in the `package.json` file, you can have the environment variables set in the test commands for various env in the `scripts` , like this

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
  "test1": "URL=www.test1.com mocha --reporter spec",
  "test2": "URL=www.test2.com mocha --reporter spec",
  .
  .
},
...
```

Similarly you can set the environment variables for the login credentials also and then pass them in the script in the same way the `URL` is passed.

Comment: Is there some other way to do this? For example if you hove some more properties that are environment specific. Is there a way to override or extend the configuration file instead of using env vars?

Comment: in this case i pass ENVIRONMENT=test or ENVIRONMENT=production etc , then i use playwright GlobalSetup that loads from a json by the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this is to use a Bash script. I use something like the following to run tests across environments, to ensure that my Playwright tests will work in all environments they're run in -

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Running tests against env 1";
ENV_URL=https://www.env1.com SOMESERVICE_ENV_URL=http://www.env1.com/scholarship npx playwright test $1;

echo "Running tests against env 2"

ENV_URL=https://env2.com SOMESERVICE_ENV_URL=http://env2.com:4008 npx playwright test $1;

echo "Running tests against env 3";

ENV_URL=http://localhost:3000 SOMESERVICE_ENV_URL=http://localhost:4008 npx playwright test $1;
```

And then run with `./myScript.sh myTest.test.ts`

(In a Bash script, the first argument passed in is available via `$1`.)